# Printing star pattern in alphabetical shape but not working

Tags: php

hii i'm trying to improve logic in php where i'm trying to print star pattern in A shape,B shape and K shape but it isnt working can anyone help me with my logic my code is as follows

```
k.php
<?php
$j = 5;    
$i = 0;  
for ($row=0; $row<=7; $row++)
{
    for ($column=0; $column<=7; $column++)
      {
        if ($column == 1 or (($row == $column + 1) and $column != 0))
            echo "*";   
        else if ($row == $i and $column == $j)
           {  
              echo "*";    
              $i=$i+1;  
              $j=$j-1;
           }
        else
            echo " ";   
}    
     echo "<br>";    
}
?>
B.php
<?php
for ($row=0; $row<7; $row++)
{
  for ($column=0; $column<=7; $column++)
    {
      if ($column == 1 or (($row == 0 or $row == 3 or $row == 6) and ($column < 5 and $column > 2)) or ($column == 5 and ($row != 0 and $row != 3 and $row != 6)))
            echo "*";    
        else  
            echo " ";     
    }        
  echo "<br>";
}
?>
A.php
<?php
 for ($row=0; $row<=7; $row++)
{
  for ($column=0; $column<=7; $column++)
    {
        if ((($column == 1 or $column == 5) and $row != 0) or (($row == 0 or $row == 3) and ($column > 1 and $column < 5)))
            echo "*";    
        else  
            echo " ";     
    }        
  echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

my code isnt working as expected please anyone help

Comment: If you want to maintain spaces when displaying the HTML in browser, you need to wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags. Otherwise multiple spaces are displayed as one. You could also replace the spaces with non-breakable spaces `&nbsp;` but you would also need to use fixed-width font for nicer output (<pre> does that automatically)

Comment: In a console your code works fine https://3v4l.org/XIbJq , https://3v4l.org/PKWYA , https://3v4l.org/i8CsX

Comment: ya but in notepad it isnt working is there any better way to do this may be more simpler...

Comment: As Jan wrote, pre tag.

Comment: now with pre tag it is working but i want to know if there is more simpler way to do this...

Comment: What can be possibly simpler way than that?

Comment: with simpler i meant more simpler logic than mine...

Comment: @john yes, you can read my last answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<pre><?php echo getK();?></pre>
<pre><?php echo getA();?></pre>
<pre><?php echo getB();?></pre>

<?php
function getK()
{
    $j = 5;
    $i = 0;
    for ($row=0; $row<=7; $row++)
    {
        for ($column=0; $column<=7; $column++)
        {
            if ($column == 1 or (($row == $column + 1) and $column != 0))
                echo "*";
            else if ($row == $i and $column == $j)
            {
                echo "*";
                $i=$i+1;
                $j=$j-1;
            }
            else
                echo " ";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}

function getA()
{
    for ($row=0; $row<=7; $row++)
    {
        for ($column=0; $column<=7; $column++)
        {
            if ((($column == 1 or $column == 5) and $row != 0) or (($row == 0 or $row == 3) and ($column > 1 and $column < 5)))
                echo "*";
            else
                echo " ";
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}

function getB()
{
    for ($row=0; $row<7; $row++)
    {
        for ($column=0; $column<=7; $column++)
        {
            if ($column == 1 or (($row == 0 or $row == 3 or $row == 6) and ($column < 5 and $column > 2)) or ($column == 5 and ($row != 0 and $row != 3 and $row != 6)))
                echo "*";
            else
                echo " ";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more answer:

legend:

```
n = "new line (\n)"
* = letter (you can use, bettor for you)
space = space)))

for example: "a" => " *** n
                     *   *n
                     *   *n
                     *****n
                     *   *n
                     *   *n
                     *   *",
```

Code:

```
<?php
$letters = [
    "a" => " *** n*   *n*   *n*****n*   *n*   *n*   *",
    "b" => "**** n*   *n*   *n****n*   *n*   *n**** ",
    "k" => "*   *n*  *n* *n**n* *n*  *n*   *",
];

function printLetter($pattern)
{
    $len = strlen($pattern);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if ($pattern[$i] == 'n') {
            echo "\n";
            continue;
        }
        echo $pattern[$i];
    }
}

?>
<pre><?php printLetter($letters['a']); ?></pre>
<pre><?php printLetter($letters['b']); ?></pre>
<pre><?php printLetter($letters['k']); ?></pre>
```